# MongoDb Why isn't the data being stored in the database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, promise, callback

I have this mongodb model:

```
  let businessLineDashboardRow = new Schema({
    ref: {
      type: String
    },
    riskstatements: {
      type: String
    },
    maximpact: {
      type: String
    },
    controleffectiveness: {
      type: String
    },
    recommendedriskrating: {
      type: String
    },
    frequency: {
      type: String
    },
    impact: {
      type: String
    },
    validatedreviewriskrating: {
      type: String
    },
    rationalforriskadjustment: {
      type: String
    }
  })
```

I started with a simple document insertion:

> db.businesslinedashboards.find()

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d10a0a6df45c71a6c9dab26"), 
  "ref" : "R13", "riskstatements" : "blablablablablabla", 
  "maximpact" : "I AM TRYING TO CHANGE THIS VALUE", 
  "controleffectiveness" : "blablablablablabla", 
  "recommendedriskrating" : "blablablablablabla", 
  "frequency" : "blablablablablabla", 
  "impact" : "blablablablablabla", 
  "validatedreviewriskrating" : "blablablablablabla", 
  "rationalforriskadjustment" : "blablablablablabla", "__v" : 0 
}
```

As you may have noticed, I am trying to change the value of maximpact, by this code:

```
 BusinessLineDashboard.findOne({
        ref: 'R13'
    }, (err, rowData) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            rowData.maximpact = 'THE DATA GETS STORED IN THE DB SUCCESFULLY'

            console.log('rowData: ', rowData.maximpact);
            //In the console: rowData:  THE DATA GETS STORED IN THE DB SUCCESFULLY
        }
 });
```

So I though it worked. But, when I sent a second query for retrieving the table data, I noticed that nothing changed:

```
function getTableData(dbtable, callback) {
    dbtable.find((err, tableData) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            callback(tableData)
        }
    }).then((tableData) => {});
}

getTableData(BusinessLineDashboard, (BLDtable) => {
        BLDtable.forEach(rowData => {
            if(rowData.ref==='R13'){
                console.log('BLDrow: ', rowData.maximpact);
                //In the console: BLDrow:  I AM TRYING TO CHANGE THIS VALUE
            }
        })
})
```

So actually nothing changed. I think this has something to do with the asynchronous nature of JS.
Any idea why is this happening and maybe how to fix it?
Thanks!!

Comment: IIRC, you cannot *both* pass a callback and expect a promise to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update maximpact in BusinessLineDashboard table corresponding to ref: 'R13'. Without update how could you change the value.

Use BusinessLineDashboard.update({ref: 'R13'},{maximpact : 'THE DATA GETS STORED IN THE DB SUCCESFULLY'})